# Writing a list into a .dat in R using write.table

Tags: r, list, file, for-loop, write.table

I'm trying to write the number list that this loop produces into a file.
I using the code below I have been able to do that, but the output is not exactly what I'm looking for.
I know I need to use write.table and it needs to be saved as a .dat 
 
Can anyone tell me why the "x" is printing in between each line?
**What I am getting in the file:** 
x 
1800 
x 
1804 
x 
1808 
x 
etc...

**What I want:** 
1804 
1808 
1812 
etc...

```
years <- seq(1800,2020)

for (i in years){
  i_div_400 <- i%%400
  if (i_div_400 == 0 & (i%%4 == 0 && i%%100 != 0)){
    write.table(i, "file.dat", append=TRUE, sep=",", quote=FALSE)  
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that's the output you are getting? `i_div_400 == 0` is only true once every 400 years. It shouldn't be writing anything. But `write.table` expects to write a data.frame with column names and such. If you just want to write a literal value, consider `writeLines()` instead. Also it would be more efficient to generate the list of values you want to write before you actually write it.

Comment: Sorry, you're right, I posted the wrong cell before. I edited the post with the correct code

Comment: Why are you doing `leap <- matrix(i)` when you are not using `leap` anywhere? Also I don't understand why you have two separate `if` condition when the code inside both the `if` condition is exactly the same.

Comment: that matrix should have been commented out. the if wasn't working as one line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why you get "x" in the output is because that is the default column names when using `write.table`. If you don't want to include column name in the output use `col.names = FALSE` and it will print only numbers in the output.

```
years <- seq(1800,2020)

for (i in years){
  i_div_400 <- i%%400
  if (i_div_400 == 0 || (i%%4 == 0 && i%%100 != 0)){
    write.table(i, "file.dat", append=TRUE, sep=",", 
               row.names=FALSE, quote=FALSE, col.names = FALSE)  
  }
}
```

---

Also this can be written in a vectorised way without a loop.

```
write.table(years[years %% 400 == 0 | (years %% 4 == 0 & years %%100 != 0)], 
          "file.dat", sep=",", row.names=FALSE, quote=FALSE, col.names = FALSE)
```